# Error:Cause: com.android.sdklib.repository.FullRevision

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, instant-run

I wanted to try instant-run from AS 2.0 - for this to work I had to update to build-plugin to 2.0.0-alpha1 - but when doing this I cannot gradle-sync the project anymore as I am getting:

```
Gradle 'SCR' project refresh failed
  Error:Cause: com.android.sdklib.repository.FullRevision
```

Anyone knows the reason/workaround for this?

Comment: Same problem here. But only happens on one of the projects which uses some native libraries (e.g. Here Maps SDK). Similar situation?

Comment: nope no native libs - just tried it with this project: https://github.com/ligi/SCR

Comment: I thought it might be the native libs because on a similar project that uses same sort of architecture and libs it works just fine! Have no idea why I'm getting this error on this particular project.

Comment: Just did a quick comparison on 3rd parties we're both using and I found the culprit: Jake Wharton's SDK Manager plugin! Still have no idea why though.

Comment: Try this workaround. It worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916808/errorcause-com-android-sdklib-repository-fullrevision?rq=1

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Quick answer for anyone in the same situation:

It's Jake Wharton's **SDK Manager plugin.**

Already fixed: https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin/pull/100.

As some of you pointed out, it's been a while since the latest release, so you might want to use the jitpack.io workaround provided in the answer below

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/33889117/1673540)

Comment: Last sdk-manager-plugin release was on Jul 12, 2014 when android plugin was `0.12`. It may be wise to start using jitpack version from the answer below.

Comment: Yeah you're right. We should go back to Eclipse ADT and manually copying libraries into our workspace and using Ant for flavors! That was good life.

Answer (score 63):

In case you want to keep the SDK Manager plugin, you can get the fixed committed version with :

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

classpath 'com.github.JakeWharton:sdk-manager-plugin:220bf7a88a7072df3ed16dc8466fb144f2817070'
```

Not ideal though!

Comment: Thanks for this. I was seriously loosing my mind trying to figure out what was different in this project an all of my other ones.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. At least not in my experience. I end up with a lot of new errors.

Comment: ```10:08:06 AM Gradle sync failed: Could not find org.rauschig:jarchivelib:0.6.0.
            Searched in the following locations:
            https://maven.fabric.io/public/org/rauschig/jarchivelib/0.6.0/jarchivelib-0.6.0.pom
            https://maven.fabric.io/public/org/rauschig/jarchivelib/0.6.0/jarchivelib-0.6.0.jar
            https://jitpack.io/org/rauschig/jarchivelib/0.6.0/jarchivelib-0.6.0.pom
            https://jitpack.io/org/rauschig/jarchivelib/0.6.0/jarchivelib-0.6.0.jar
            Required by:
            ...```

Comment: I updated the committed version to the latest and it works again: `classpath 'com.github.JakeWharton:sdk-manager-plugin:1d29782dd6ffa18880c8cbada748fb3dea45e7be'`

Comment: Even this also doesn't work anymore, can anyone of you guys tell me how to get the latest version?

Comment: Still works for me - I think your problem is you replaced jcenter completely - please do 
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    jcenter()
}