# Error:Cause: com.android.sdklib.repository.FullRevision

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I wanted to try instant-run from AS 2.0 - for this to work I had to update to build-plugin to 2.0.0-alpha6 - but when doing this I cannot gradle-sync the project anymore as I am getting:

> Gradle 'myProject' project refresh failed
>     Error:Cause: com.android.sdklib.repository.FullRevision
>   Anyone knows the reason/workaround for this?

I use **JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin**.
build-plugin to 1.5.0 is not problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881984/errorcause-com-android-sdklib-repository-fullrevision/33889117#33889117 Some people have had success with this post

Answer (score 18):

In my project I have added

```
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
```

I removed it from the gradle file of App & it worked.

Hope will help you.

Comment: You are an angel' my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to mark out `'apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'` from the project's `'build.gradle'` file. Obviously, environment and project's configurations vary, however, marking it out and allowing

```
dependencies{

.....

classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.10+'

}
```

handle the plugin resolved this issue.